# How to use an index within another index to locate a change in a variable - R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, indexing, indices

I have the following dataset.

```
id<-c(1001,1001,1001,1002,1002,1003,1004,1005,1005,1005)
year<-c(2010,2013,2016, 2013,2010,2010,2016,2016,2010,2013)
status<-c(2,2,2,3,4,2,1,1,1,5)
df<-data.frame(id, year, status)
df <- df[order(df$id, df$year), ]
```

My goal is to create a for-loop with two indices one for `id` and the other for `year` so that it runs through the `id` first and then within each `id` it looks at `years` in which there was a change in the `status`. To record the changes with this loop, I want another variable that shows in which the change happened.
For example, in the dataframe below the variable `change` records 0 for `id` 1001 in all three years. But for 1002, a change in status is recorded with 1 in year 2013. For 1005, status changes twice, in 2013 and 2016, that's why 1 is recorded twice. btw, id is a character variable because the real data I am working on has alpha-numeric ids.

```
     id year status change
1  1001 2010      2   0
2  1001 2013      2   0
3  1001 2016      2   0
5  1002 2010      4   0
4  1002 2013      3   1
6  1003 2010      2   0
7  1004 2016      1   0
9  1005 2010      1   0
10 1005 2013      2   1
8  1005 2016      1   1
```

The actual dataframe has over 600k observations. Loop takes a lot of time running. I am open to faster solutions too.

My code is below:

```
df$change<-NA df$id<-as.character(df$id) for(id in unique(df$id)) {
    tau<-df$year[df$id==id]   if (length(tau)>1) {
    for( j in 1:(length(tau)-1)){ 
      if (df$status[df$year==tau[j] & df$id==id] != df$status[df$year==tau[j+1]& df$id==id]) {
       df$change[df$year==tau[j]    & df$id==id]<-0
       df$change[df$year==tau[j+1]  & df$id==id]<-1
    } else {
       df$change[df$year==tau[j]    & df$id==id]<-0
       df$change[df$year==tau[j+1]  & df$id==id]<-0
    }}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

Base R:

```
df |> 
 transform(change = ave(status, id, FUN = \(x)c(0, diff(x))!=0))
```

In tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(change = c(0, diff(status)!=0))

      id  year status change
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  1001  2010      2      0
 2  1001  2013      2      0
 3  1001  2016      2      0
 4  1002  2010      4      0
 5  1002  2013      3      1
 6  1003  2010      2      0
 7  1004  2016      1      0
 8  1005  2010      1      0
 9  1005  2013      5      1
10  1005  2016      1      1
```

Comment: like the usage of c(0, diff...

Comment: Thank you for the codes. The one with tidyverse worked fine. However, the base codes you posted did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Does this yield the correct result?

```
library(dplyr)

id<-c(1001,1001,1001,1002,1002,1003,1004,1005,1005,1005)
year<-c(2010,2013,2016, 2013,2010,2010,2016,2016,2010,2013)
status<-c(2,2,2,3,4,2,1,1,1,5)
df<-data.frame(id, year, status)
df <- df[order(df$id, df$year), ]

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(change = as.numeric(status != lag(status,
                                           default = first(status))))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       id  year status change
#>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1  1001  2010      2      0
#>  2  1001  2013      2      0
#>  3  1001  2016      2      0
#>  4  1002  2010      4      0
#>  5  1002  2013      3      1
#>  6  1003  2010      2      0
#>  7  1004  2016      1      0
#>  8  1005  2010      1      0
#>  9  1005  2013      5      1
#> 10  1005  2016      1      1
```

Note: I put the "NA replacement" in a second mutate since this step does not have to be on the grouped data which is then faster for large datasets

Comment: With `dplyr`, `change = ifelse(is.na(change), 0, change)` can be nicer as `change = coalesce(change, 0)`

Comment: debatable since ifelse might be more understandable to others but coalesce is indeed more elegant!

Comment: `coalesce` is fairly widely known as it's [the standard name for this operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator).

Comment: You can use `default=first(status)` as an argument to `lag()`, and drop the second `mutate` call. Seems much clearer. See my answer for that.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. updated the answer

Comment: Hi! the default option is getting an error. :( There are multiple packages that have a lag function. Which one are you using?

Comment: The answer works on its own in a clean R session. As you see, only dplyr is used

Comment: Hi, for some reason the default option was not working with `lag()` in `mutate()`. As I knew the values I want to have in place of where NA was created, I simply replaced the NAs with that value. Thank! :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ifelse` with a logical comparison between `status` and `lag(status)`. The key is the argument `default = first(status)`, which eliminates common problems with NAs in the output.

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
mutate(change=ifelse(status==lag(status, default = first(status)), 0, 1))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   id [5]
      id  year status change
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  1001  2010      2      0
 2  1001  2013      2      0
 3  1001  2016      2      0
 4  1002  2010      4      0
 5  1002  2013      3      1
 6  1003  2010      2      0
 7  1004  2016      1      0
 8  1005  2010      1      0
 9  1005  2013      5      1
10  1005  2016      1      1
```

Comment: I was wondering how this can be done using for-loops. I am trying to see it for an exercise.